# How powerful is Carrot's Sulong, when compared among the Strawhats?

Tags: one-piece

My order of strawhats power would be something like this:

*Zoro(I feel he is more powerful than the protogonist), Luffy, Sanji, Brook, Robin, Franky, Chopper, God(Ussop), Nami.* (Power in the sense, I would say how quick/fast one can finish the battle).

So, when compared to them where would carrot's sulong stand. Also correct me if my order is wrong about strawhats.

I follow only anime, and I don't remember seeing Luffy as powerful as Zoro. At least he toys around for quite a long and then yeah somehow(when you get bored of the fight) he wins the fight.

Comment: I doubt anyone can give you an exact answer since there is no concrete way we can rank the SH in term of power. Sanji,Zoro and Luffy are considered to be the "strong trio"  and by extension of that we can consider them the "three strongest members". Where Carrot fits in, we can only argue about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the Straw Hats ranking, the 2 extremes are already known; Luffy is the strongest (cause he is the captain) and Usopp is the weakest (Oda said so himself  in the ONE PIECE 10th Treasures (2007) where he states that "Usopp has been and will be the weakest in strawhats.") The link to the interviews can be found [in this thread.](http://forums.arlongpark.net/showthread.php?t=42229)

I'm definitely sure for a fact, that Carrot is normally way stronger than Ussopp, Nami, and Robin, and I'll give reasons for that.

Members of the [Mink Tribe](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mink_Tribe) have formidable physical abilities, which are far superior to normal humans, this stands to reason that Carrot is naturally stronger than Robin, Nami and Usopp (all of who are average in strength [and are the 3 weakest in the straw Hat team based on power])

When the Sulong transformation is used, along with her altered appearances, Carrots strength and speed also vastly increase. At that point she is probably stronger than Chopper and Brook.

As for the remaining members of the Straw Hat team, It will be very difficult to precisely conclude their exact ranking with respect to the Sulong transformation. (Mainly because there isn't sufficient information on her transformation.)

> My personal ranking of the Straw Hats is as follows: Luffy is first, Jimbei is second strongest, Sanji and Zoro are a tie for third (cause they are super rivals and it seems to me that they are almost equal in strength), Franky is the fourth strongest, followed by Brook, Chopper, Robin, Nami and then God Usopp. But then again since we haven't been told the exact ranking from Oda himself, we can only speculate based on the information we have.

Hope that helps.